# How to disable version control features in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using an independent version control management program (SmartGit) alongside Qt Creator, and I would prefer not to use Qt Creator for version control management.

It is becoming a nuisance that Qt always prompts me regarding whether I'd like to add new files to Git (when I add new files to the Qt Creator project), and whether I'd like to remove files from Git (when I remove files from the project).

Earlier today, I mistakenly added a file to Git through Qt Creator when adding a new file to the Qt Creator project.  A few minutes later, I wished to temporarily remove the file from the project (likely to be re-added later).  When I removed the file, Qt Creator dutifully asked me if I'd like to remove the file from version control - giving me a warning that the file might be removed permanently from the file system.  Understanding the risk, I nonetheless decided to test the behavior and I said "yes, remove the file from Git as well as removing it from the project".  Just as the warning forewarned, the file was removed from the file system and I then had to reconstruct it.

I could simply live with it and occasionally use Qt Creator's version control features in addition to SmartGit's, and/or I could use SmartGit directly to deal with any mistaken occasional uses ogreatf Qt Creator's version control features.  However, I'd rather simply disable Qt Creator's version control features entirely, for convenience.

I looked through every Qt Creator option I could find in order to see if it is possible to disable Qt Creator's version control features (even if the project's files are under version control).  Unfortunately, I cannot find an option to disable Qt Creator's version control features, anywhere.  A careful Google search also revealed nothing.

Is it possible to disable Qt Creator's version control features, even if the project's files are under version control?  If so, how is it done?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Help->About Plugins... and deselect the version control plugins.

Comment: (P.S. I looked through **every single menu** EXCEPT the Help menu.  I can't think of any other program that has program feature settings in the Help menu. Ha!)

Comment: Yeah, it should be in preferences.  It also shouldn't be called *About* Plugins, as 99% of the time you aren't accessing it to read the plugin About blurb...

Comment: I'm pretty sure Eclipse does as well

Comment: Long ago I gave up on hoping to find this solution. Today I just found this post by chance - thank you so much!

Comment: You just helped me out so much. I had much earlier turned off the version control plugins and then recently wanted to turn them back on and for the life of me couldn't figure out how. Never would have checked the Help menu. Thx!

Comment: [Move and rename "About Plugins"](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-14993)

Comment: How do I disable version control per project?  i.e. For some projects I want Qt to manage the version control, but not for other projects.

Comment: @RobinHsu Post a new question.